# How to keep showing 5 div items at a time on click html event pressing a show more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so, I ahve a list `$top_type_subtype_list` where I get a class list of things for a total of 30 items i need to click a show more button to keep showing 5 more divs in the next row at a time as I only used hide class for the next items after 5. So i need to take out the `hide` class of the next 5 and so on

```
<div>
<section class="container p-t p-b">
    <div class="row p-t p-b">
        <?php $count = 0;?>
        @foreach($top_type_subtype_list as $top_filter)
            <?php if($count<5):?>
            <div class="col s4 m2 m-t center">
                <a><img src="{{asset('assets/materialTheme/svg/types/'.$top_filter->getValue().'.svg')}}" alt="Publicar vehículos gratis"/></a>
                @foreach($top_filter->getValues() as $model_values)
                    <p><a href="{{$model_values->getHref()}}">{{$model_values->getValue()}}</a></p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <?php else:?>
            <div class="col s4 m2 m-t center hide">
                <a><img src="{{asset('assets/materialTheme/svg/types/'.$top_filter->getValue().'.svg')}}" alt="Publicar vehículos gratis"/></a>
                @foreach($top_filter->getValues() as $model_values)
                    <p><a href="{{$model_values->getHref()}}">{{$model_values->getValue()}}</a></p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $count++;?>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: php is useless here, html is useful. Where is your CSS ? javascript would easily do this, CSS will require some trick and extra HTML such as form elements ... unles it is a php/ajax question ?

Comment: ye i didn't intend to use php to do this but i get my object from php

Comment: see source of page displayed in browser and you'll get the HTML rendered/send from PhP server ;)

Comment: u want the html rendered? it just print out divs

Comment: the best is , i guess to share this link with you, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it matters to you in order to get efficient help actually ;)